# Using DAX to get a table from nested table

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In powerBI, I using the python script and generate one table. The generated table is a nested table. Each row value is actually a table. and so now I want to use DAX to copy one specific row value(which is a table), just the "dataset_filtered" table shown as below.

what's the DAX code for this ? or any good suggestions ?

[The nested table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tewlr.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is M rather than DAX.

1. Click the drop down arrow in the name column to filter the row you want.
2. Click the expand arrows in the Value column to expand the table.

Comment: your operation is just to do the filter work. Actaully what I want is that in the PowerQuery Editor, I want to generate a nested table which contains the dataset and dataset_filtered. And in the powerBI main table, I want then copy the dataset and daset_filtered and then based these two table then generate different dashboard. So I want to use the DAX to copy each table from the nested table, any ideas?

Comment: DAX doesn't work like this. A table datatype in PQ cannot be manipulated in DAX unless its constituent columns are expanded.